# How to unmarshal nested child element(containing < & >) if the schema is not known for the child element. I can't use &lt; &gt; in xml.

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

Customer Schema :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

String name;
int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@XmlElement
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Code for unmarshalling :

```
public static void unmarshalXml2Obj() {

    try {

        File file = new File(
                "D:/Workspace/CustomerFile.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(customer);
        System.out.println("ID : " + customer.getId());
        System.out.println("Name : " + customer.getName());
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

XML to be unmarshalled :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer >
  <id>100</id>
  <name><FN>Johny</FN><LN>Depp</LN><a>AAAA</a><z>ZZZZ</z></name>
</customer>
```

Output :

```
test.example.Customer@eeb406
ID : 100
Name : 
-------------------------
```

When not using angular brackets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer >
  <id>100</id>
  <name>&lt;FN&gt;Johny&lt;/FN&gt;&lt;LN&gt;Depp&lt;/LN&gt;&lt;a&gt;AAAA&lt;/a&gt;&lt;z&gt;ZZZZ&lt;/z&gt;</name>
</customer>
```

Correct Output :

```
test.example.Customer@7a279c
ID : 100
Name : <FN>Johny</FN><LN>Depp</LN><a>AAAA</a><z>ZZZZ</z>
-------------------------
```

I cant use &lt &gt in my xml. Need solution to use Angular brackets(< and >) only.

Comment: The problem here is we cant control(alter) the XML, can we do something at our end only without changing the XML data.

Comment: In this case, your name can be seen as a parent tag for the first name, last name and date, you have to create a separate class which will hold the data about these tags, so you can access them. I'm not familiar with Unmarshaller but this seems how it works.

Comment: [This](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html) tutorial might be helpfull for you. State can be watched as the name tag in your case. Just do some modifications/addings and you will get the desire output.

Comment: Hi @drgPP, Thanks for the support. As I said earlier, the schema for child element is not known. We cannot create the class Name as its variables are unknown. However, if we can implement <![CDATA[]]> in java, it will allow us to handle the XML from our end without changing the original XML.